# How can we compare the maneuverability of the F-16 Block 60 and J-10C?

Tags: f-16

Since [J-10 originated from the IAI Lavi project](https://www.latimes.com/archives/la-xpm-1994-12-28-mn-13774-story.html), people assume that they are very close to F-16 in terms of maneuverability.

[image]

How can we compare the maneuverability of the F-16 Block 60 and J-10C?

Comment: A series of flight tests would be a good start.

Comment: @MichaelHall, is there any such test data available in the public domain?

Comment: Afraid not. Fighter manufacturers do release some performance data, but quite unsurprisingly it is limited, and not necessarily fully accurate.

Comment: @Jpe61, [Chengdu J-10 vs F-16 E/F Fighting Falcon BLOCK 60](https://aviatia.net/j-10-vs-f-16/#%3A~%3Atext%3DAlso%20the%20F-16%20has%2CF-16%20have%20been%20produced)

Comment: Yes, that site is based on data I described. The guys who put that  together did **not** test fly the planes. They have not even seen many (most) of them live.

Comment: OK, so it seems like you've got a comparison there. Is that unsatisfactory to you in some way or is that your answer? If it's an answer, put it down there in the "Answer" box and give yourself a check mark. If it's unsatisfactory, [edit] your post, include the link, and be _explicit_ about what additional info you're looking for.

Comment: Block 60 isn't a good comparison because it's more of a ground attack airplane. The external thanks are heavy and breaks the aerodynamics.

Comment: @user3528438, which one is a better comparison?

Comment: I am curious about how the J-10 originated from IAI Lavi, because they are very different designs...

Comment: @Jpe61, [U.S. Says Israel Gave Combat Jet Plans to China](https://www.latimes.com/archives/la-xpm-1994-12-28-mn-13774-story.html)

Comment: Maybe block 50/52. See in your picture F16 Block 60 carries heavy tanks and an air-to-surface aiming module and no AA missiles, while the J10 carries all AA missiles and no external tank.

Comment: Thanks @user366312 this is new for me. Still I must say, they drifted very far from Lavi, very different configurations.